# Help: Replacing a Leviton Dimmable switch with a Regular Switch

Tags: wiring, lighting, dimmer-switch

I'm a newbie when it comes to installing light switches. My staircase light would randomly turn on in the middle of the night and it has 3 dimmable Leviton light switches that control the staircase light. I've already successfully changed one of the three light switches to a regular light switch. However, when I'm attempting the second light switch, I'm super confused on how to connect the wires and screws.

- 2 black wires connected to the black screw
- 2 Red Wires connected to a copper screw
- 1 white wire connected to a silver screw
- 1 Copper Wire connected to green screw

Here is the original setup of the Leviton Dimmable switch:
[image]

Here's my new switch that I'm trying to install:
[image]

What I have attempted so far (I know I'm doing something wrong here). Please advise.

Light Switch 2 Attempt
[image]

Back of Dimmer
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: In the original case the white and black wires were on opposing sides. Why did you reverse them in your attempt?

Comment: I thought Red Wires were always suppose to be on the same side as the ground wire that is connected to the green screw.

Comment: Ground wire screw placement is completely arbitrary. It tells you nothing about the other connections.

Comment: Post also picture of that sticker on back of dimmer.

Comment: White screw is neutral. Regular switch do not have neutral.  Regular switch is 3-way? Some mix-up.

Comment: so cap the white wire that's connected to a gold screw with a nut. then move the left black wire to the gold screw? Is my setup on the other side with the ground wire correct and red wires correct?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes please?

Comment: With 3 switches 2 will normally be 3 way, each of these 2 switches have 3 wires + the ground And 1ea 4 way switch 4 wires and the ground. It is possible and quite likely that a white wire is NOT a neutral but could be a hot . Getting the connections for each of the switches will be needed. It is possible that mechanical switches can not be used if enough conductors were not used (some electronic switches do not need all the above connections) in this case we need photos of each switch to figure it out. I see 2 3 way switches

Comment: On switches, positioning does not matter because every model of switch is different (I even suspect you'll find the same models mirror-imaged because it's easier to stamp the parts!)  Further, due to the nature of 3-way circuits, color codes are meaningless too.  Yes, 3-ways where the last guy did something weird *are extremely novice-hostile*.

Comment: Can you post photos that look into the *backs* of the boxes in question please? That's far more helpful than just being able to see which wires connect to which screws...

Answer (score 1):

Here is how "old-school" 3-way wiring works.   Black is always-hot, white is neutral.

[image]

Here is how 4-way wiring works.

[image]

Note how the 4-way switch changes very little about the wiring.  This second diagram shows that the wiring sequence could vary.

Your smart-switches are using the wiring in a completely different way.  You will need to figure out how to reallocate the wires to find 2 "travelers".

Of course your wires are not yellow. **There are no color codes for 3-way wiring**. Certain wires must be certain colors because of Code requirements; the travelers get the wires that are left.  I am extremely fond of *re-marking* them yellow using a pack of multi-color electrical tape... but they don't get that way by themselves.